problemas con el acceso con una app de springboot a drive api
estoy en el desarrollo de una app que pueda hacer un crud, y que pueda subir imagenes con google drive api, el problema está en que el acceso de mi app me lo bloquea

he tratado de todo... verificar si mis credenciales estan completas y coinciden con mi properties, en cualquier caso, aqui lo comparto
application.properties:
spring.application.name=emp_system
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emp
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Paradise30#
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=810099858291-jetevhonvd2leen5i301hg3lgs9b61if.apps.googleusercontent.com
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=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
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080

y mis credentials.json así:
    {
    "web": {
      "client_id": "810099858291-jetevhonvd2leen5i301hg3lgs9b61if.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "project_id": "optimal-sentry-430719-q0",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_secret": "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",
      "redirect_uris": [
        "http://localhost:8080"
      ]
    }
  }


ahora... se supone que coincide con el id del cliente 0auth

y el uri de redireccionamiento asi

deseo poder resolver el problema del acceso bloqueado para subir imagenes a drive desde mi app, si necesitan mas info la brindaré
quiero resolver mi problema de bloqueo de acceso de mi app a la api google drive y pueda subir imagenes

Pusiste tus claves secretas en la pregunta??? invalida todo inmediatamente... podemos arreglar la pregunta, pero ya nada sirve.. por favor confirma eso...


Revisa tu pom.xml y dependencias para Google API Client y Spring
Security OAuth2.
Asegúrate de que el scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file esté habilitado para tu aplicación en la consola de Google Cloud.
Comprueba el token de Google Drive API
Después de estos pasos revisa tu CRUD

